# Where can I find a replacement bathroom fan with this uncommon electrical plug?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, repair, exhaust-fan

I’m replacing my bathroom exhaust fan. I planned to do this myself and watched a few how-tos. It looked easy. You basically just plug the new one in. The thing is that our bathroom fan seems to have a different kind of electrical plug than what is common. In the how-tos I’ve watched all the fans have a “normal” two prong plug. Looks a lot like a lamp plug. However, my plug has 3 holes and looks like this: [image]

This plug fits nicely into the similar looking “outlet” in the ceiling.

Where can I find a replacement fan with this type of plug? OR - is there a way to get a common two prong plug to work with my existing outlet?

Edit: I’ve now discovered this is called a molex connector!

Based on that info I found this similar post on a different stack exchange site: [similar post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/205035/how-do-i-replace-this-bathroom-fan-with-a-different-plug)

Comment: That's a "Molex connector" if it helps your search process. They are not uncommon at all.

Comment: Thank you! I haven’t heard of that yet in all of my searching.

Comment: You will also need to get the pins it looks like you have female , you can actually depin that and reuse it with new pins cost almost nothing ea but finding in small qty may be the hard part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be seeking out that connector.

The problem is, you have not removed the fan. You've removed only part of the fan assembly.  The thing that plugs into is more parts of the fan assembly. Remove it too.

That particular fan is designed to break into halves: there's the half that mounts in the ceiling (first) and then half that latches into it once it's installed.  The two halves interconnect using that "proprietary" connector (meaning: it's peculiar to that make/model of fan; fans generally do not use that connector; it's not a standard.)

Just take the rest of the fan out of the ceiling until you are looking at a Romex cable and/or a junction box.